# Maximum number of subqueries that are allowed in a single SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to insert multiple subqueries into a single query. For two to three subqueries, the database is running normally. But when I insert some more statements, SQLite engine is giving "Parser stack overflow" error. My doubt is, is there any maximum for subqueries? Why this error occurs normally?

Comment: Please post the full SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_expr_depth), the maximum depth of an expression tree is 1000.

If you are running into this limit, you are doing something wrong.
(What *are* you doing?)

Comment: Ok @CL. I will try to reduce the depth of my expression.

Comment: Using EntityFramework and PredicateBuilder this can happen easily.

Comment: @springy76 I think I'm encountering that now... difficult to troubleshoot EF for me though.